# How to show the sequence $a_n=ne^n,n\ge 1$ is increasing by comparison with a function who has domain on real numbers?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to show the sequence $a_n=ne^n,n\ge 1$ is increasing by comparison with a function who has domain on real numbers?

We easily use derivative to show $a_n$ is increasing on $n\ge 1$. But how do you find a function that can compare with it?

Comment: Are you looking for $x \mapsto xe^x$?

Answer (score 0):

All the ordered pairs $(n,a_n)$ such that
$$a_n=ne^n,n\ge 1$$
are elements of the set $$(x,xe^x)$$
So they all follow a common mathematical behaviour.That is, if $xe^x$ is increasing for all real numbers then its the same for all natural numbers.And as $xe^x$ is increasing in $R$ then its the same for $N$.
I hope this was helpful